# How to avoid checking whether value is undefined when function returns error and value in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Given a function that returns a useful value and an error value when things go wrong, I'm trying to avoid checking whether the useful value is `undefined` when there is no error,

```
const someFunc = (): {error?: Error, value?: string} => { /* ... */ }
```

After calling the above function, we can check whether there's an error. However, even if there's no error, we still have to check whether `value` is defined.

```
const { error, value } = someFunc();

if (error) {
  /* handle error */
  // return something
  // throw something
}

// This is necessary b/c `value` could be undefined. 
// Yet it is "impossible" for value to be undefined if code execution reaches this point
if (!value) {
  throw Error('Expected `value` to be defind');
}

// only now can `value` be used without it being *|undefined
console.log(value.toUpperCase);
```

Is there a better type or error handling pattern that would allow to handle errors in a similar way while avoiding having to check for `value` to be defined?

Comment: Here is a nice clean pattern that might help you https://github.com/David-Else/modern-typescript-with-examples-cheat-sheet#reading-json-from-localstorage-using-unknown-example

Answer (score 0):

Why not throwing errors in the function. The first one instead of returning `error?: Error` and the second one in case `value === undefined`. You would end up with: `const sumFunc = (): string => {...}`. The function you could wrap in a try-catch.

Comment: There are many valid scenarios that the method should not decide on throwing or returning an error. The decision may need to be taken by calling methods. If you read the comments, it says "return something / throw something".